# First digit difference between two numbers

Tags: numerics

I was trying to build a function that finds the first decimal place difference between two decimal numbers of same sign. An example:

```
FirstDecimalPlaceDifference[0.00000456,0.00000478]

Out:10^-7
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your requirements?  We have plenty of ideas, but we're not sure which ones you want!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function returns the location of the first place at which the decimal representations of the given numbers differ.

```
firstDecimalPlaceDifference[x__] := 
 If[Equal @@ SetPrecision[{x}, Infinity], 0, 
  10^NestWhile[# - 1 &, Floor[Log10@Max[Abs[{x}]]], 
    Equal @@ RealDigits[{x}, 10, 1, #] &]]
```

Not the fastest method, but guaranteed to get correct results.

First we find the largest number (`Max[Abs[{x}]]`) then we get the location of its first digit (`Floor[Log10@ % ]`).  Then we repeatedly move right one digit (`#-1 &`), stopping when the digits of the numbers in that place (`RealDigits[{x}, 10, 1, #] &`) are not equal.  If the numbers are equal to start with, then we just return `0` (otherwise we'll loop forever).

Note that the above method considers `5` and `4.999999` to differ in the ones place (returns `1`).  This function looks at the rounded representations:

```
firstDecimalPlaceDifference[x__] := 
 If[Equal @@ SetPrecision[{x}, Infinity], 0, 
  NestWhile[#/10 &, 10^Floor[Log10@Max[Abs[{x}]]], 
   Equal @@ Round[{x}, #] &]]
```

This method considers `5` and `4.999999` to differ at the seventh place (returns `1/10000000`).

### Update

I've reworked my method to take advantage of the fact that if we know the difference between two numbers is larger than $10^{-n}$, then we only need to compare up to the $n$th decimal place.  This allows use to generate all the digits we could need at once, instead of repeatedly generating them in a loop.  When comparing numbers with many digits in common, this function is faster.  However, it's slower when comparing numbers that all have more than a few digits in common.  (The breakeven point is somewhere around 30 digits on my laptop.)

```
firstDecimalPlaceDifference2[x__] :=
 With[{y = SetPrecision[{x}, Infinity]}, 
  If[Equal @@ y, 0, 
   Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = Infinity}, 
    With[{offset = Floor[Log10@Max[Abs[y]]], 
      accuracy = 1 - Floor[Log10[Max[y] - Min[y]]]}, 
     10^(1 + offset - 
        First@FirstPosition[
          Equal @@@ 
           Transpose[
            First /@ 
             RealDigits[{x}, 10, offset + accuracy + 1, offset]], 
          False, {Infinity}, {1}])]]]]
```

Comment: Note that these functions work for any number of arguments!  They return the first place at which any of the arguments differ.

Comment: as I interpret the question he literally wants to know where the digits differ so the  result of `5,4.9999` should be zero. (though it is good to show both results )

Comment: @george2079 Do you mean `10^0` (`1`)?

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of...

```
f[a_, b_] := Round[a - b, Power[10, N[IntegerPart[Round[Log[10, Abs[a - b]]]]]]]
```

Using Log10 to get the scale of the difference and rounding the difference to this Precision.

Following discussion with 2012rcampion a tidied up version only giving the scale and handling the zero case...

```
Clear[f];
f[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ] /; a - b == 0 := 0;
f[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ] := Power[10, N[IntegerPart[Round[Log[10, Abs[a - b]]]]]];
```

Comment: `f[0.1, -0.1]` returns `0.2`, not `0.1`.  Also, you should use `Abs` on the result (`f[1,2]` returns `-1.`) so that when you take the log, you don't get imaginary numbers (in this case `0. + 1.36438 I`).

Comment: On your first point its not clear the OP does't want that given the (current admittedly somewhat vague) spec.  On the second, I am using Abs down there in the Log, where will it go complex?

Comment: Try `Log10[f[1,2]]`, you end up with `0. + 1.36438 I`.  Also, pretty sure he wants a power of 10 as the result.

Comment: No question about your example there but I don't get why you want to do it. The result the OP quotes is 10^-7 (0.0000001) not -7?

Comment: Fair point.  I guess a better way to phrase it is that he's probably expecting a positive number later (e.g. `10^-7`, *not* `-10^-7`).  Trying to find the magnitude with `Log10` is just one example of how negative numbers might break downstream code.

Comment: Also, try `f[1,1]` and `f[1,3]`.  They give `Indeterminate` and `-2.`, respectively.  (Should give `0`(?) and `-1.`.)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for the simple cases i checked:

```
FirstDecimalPlaceDifference[x_, y_] :=Floor[Log[10, Abs[x - y]]]
```

?

Comment: Try `firstDecimalPlaceDifference[1, 0.1]`.  Gives `-1`, should give `0`.

Answer (score 0):

second try, restrict to number input:

```
 firstDecimalPlaceDifference[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ] := 
       Module[{aa, bb, base},
         {aa, bb} = RealDigits /@ {a, b} ;
         base = Max[aa[[2]], bb[[2]] ];
         If[aa[[2]] != bb[[2]] ,
         10^(base-1),
         {aa, bb} = Reverse@SortBy[{aa[[1]], bb[[1]]}, Length];
         If[Union[#] == {0}, 0,
         10^(base - Position[ #,
             Except[0], {1}, Heads -> False][[1, 1]])] &@
             (aa - Join[bb, ConstantArray[-1, Length[aa] - Length[bb]]]) ]]
                   /; Max[Precision /@ {a, b}] != Infinity
```

now a wrapper to handle exact input:

```
 firstDecimalPlaceDifference[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := Module[{p},
 p = If[# == Infinity , 1000 , # ] &@Min[Precision /@ {a, b}] ;
 firstDecimalPlaceDifference @@ (If[ Precision[#] == Infinity, 
          N[#, p], #] & /@ {a, b})  ]

 firstDecimalPlaceDifference[Pi, 267/85] // N
 firstDecimalPlaceDifference[0.00000456, 0.00000478] // N
 firstDecimalPlaceDifference[5, 4.9999] // N
 firstDecimalPlaceDifference[5, 5] // N
```

> 0.0001
>
> 1.*10^-7
>
> 1.
>
> 0.

```
 firstDecimalPlaceDifference @@ Convergents[Pi, 20][[-2 ;;]] // 
     N // Timing
```

> {0., 1.*10^-19}

note the `-1` argument in `ConstantArray` limits the agreement based on the precision of the input,

```
 firstDecimalPlaceDifference[1.`20, 1.`3] // N
```

> 0.0001

making that a `0` extends the low precision value with zeros causing these things to be considered equal.

Comment: This function is faster than mine for numbers that are close (although it fails on numbers equal to more than 1000 places).  However, it has some strange behavior comparing exact and approximate numbers.  For example, `f[1,1.]` returns `1/10`, since the exact form has only one digit!  When comparing approximate numbers of different precisions the behavior is also a little unexpected, e.g. ``f[1`1,1`2]``, ``f[1`2,1`2]``, and ``f[1`3,1`2]`` return `1/100`, `0`, and `1/1000` (I would have expected `1/10`, `1/100` and `1/1000`).

Comment: This one also has the same bug with `Equal` that mine had.  Try `f[1., 1 + $MachineEpsilon]` (returns `0`, should be `10^-16`).  Use `SetPrecision[_, Infinity]` to get around this one.

Comment: `RealDigits` gives you the nearrest number representable in whole powers of ten, so anything less than `~1+10^-15` or `~1+5$MachineEpsilon` gets truncated to 1.  This fine point seems beyond the scope of the question though.

Comment: bitwise equality check: `Equal @@ (RealDigits[#, 2] & /@ {1., 1. + $MachineEpsilon })  (*False*)`

Comment: Here is a much simpler version of yours that doesn't need a wrapper function or the padding logic: `f[a_, b_] := With[{m = Floor@Log10[Max[Abs[{a, b}]]]}, 10^(1 + m - First@FirstPosition[SameQ @@@ Transpose[First /@ RealDigits[{a, b}, 10, 1000, m]], False, {\[Infinity]}])]`.  As far as I can tell it behaves identically.

Comment: I did find one difference: your original function recurses infinitely when passed an exact number and zero.  (Try `f[1, 0]`. Both my function and my modified version of yours correctly return `1`.)