# Different floating-point numbers equal?

Tags: numerics, machine-precision

Let's define two different numbers.

```
x = 1.
y = 1. + 2^-52 (* equivalently, 1 + $MachineEpsilon *)
```

Let's make sure they're different with `FullForm`:

```
x // FullForm (* 1.` *)
y // FullForm (* 1.0000000000000002` *)
```

Those look pretty close... let's make sure they're different.  I'm not a wizard with the developer tools, but I can export them as IEEE double-precision floating point numbers (which I'd bet is their internal representation):

```
StringJoin @@ 
 IntegerString[Reverse@ToCharacterCode[ExportString[x, "Real64"]], 
  16, 2]
(* 3ff0000000000000 *)
StringJoin @@ 
 IntegerString[Reverse@ToCharacterCode[ExportString[y, "Real64"]], 
  16, 2]
(* 3ff0000000000001 *)
```

We can see that they are indeed different.  They represent the two numbers:

$$
\begin{align}
x &= (1.){\underbrace{000 \cdots 000}_\text{51 zeros}}0_2 \times 2^{01111111111_2 - 1023} \equiv 1 \\
y &= (1.){\underbrace{000 \cdots 000}_\text{51 zeros}}1_2 \times 2^{01111111111_2 - 1023} \equiv 1 + \frac{1}{2^{52}}
\end{align}
$$

That is, `x` is exactly one, and `y` is the smallest IEEE double greater than one.  Ok, so they're different.  Hey Mathematica, you know they're diff-

```
x == y (* True *)
```

Oh.  What if we try-

```
x === y (* True *)
```

Hey Python, you use doubles, right?  Are you seeing this?

```
>>> 1. == 1.0000000000000002
False
```

Maybe it's because you're using quads?

```
>>> 1. == 1.0000000000000001
True
```

Yeah, I didn't think so.  Mathematica, are you sure?  I mean, this doesn't seem right...

```
y - x (* 2.22045*10^-16 *)
```

Aha!  I knew it!  Now let's try this:

```
y - x == 0 (* False *)
```

Success!  Now let's just double-check (pun intended):

```
1.0000000000000001 - 1. (* 0. *)
% == 0 (* True *)
```

So you are using double-precision...

My question is, **Why do `Equal` and `SameQ` return `True`, even though these numbers are obviously different?**  `SameQ` ignores the last bit, and `Equal` ignores the last *seven* bits!

Comment: ``Internal`$EqualTolerance`` and ``Internal`$SameQTolerance``.  You can search the site for explanations

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yep, just found those in the related questions.  Should this one be closed?

Comment: That's a good question.  I didn't find an exact duplicate in my cursory search.  But I guess it's in the "Details" of the docs -- e.g., from `Equal`: "Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits)."  I would consider that "easily found in the documentation," I guess.  Others might think this is a nice clear question about an idiosyncratic behavior of *Mathematica*.  Your choice, or you could wait and see if the community closes it.

Comment: I would consider myself a pretty knowledgeable Mathematica user, and I was totally stumped by this, event though the answer is clearly in the documentation.  I won't close it myself but if someone wants to I won't object.

Comment: Yeah, there are nearly infinitely many corners of *Mathematica* and not enough time to explore them all.  (Different users have different notions of "easily found", but still, I think if the answer is clearly explained in the details of the docs for the function, I consider it easily found, even if it's a function I never heard of. But I won't vote to close. I think the issue is important and common enough, that a little extra duplication of the documentation is ok.)

Comment: Related:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983885/is-there-a-normal-equalq-function-in-mathematica

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems I found my answer in [OleksandrR's comment to this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5580/dr-strangenumbers-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-floating-point-ar?rq=1#comment15381_5582).  He says,

> Bear in mind `Equal` applies an extra tolerance in Mathematica. The proper comparison is
>
> ```
> Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = -Infinity}, 1 == 1 + $MachineEpsilon] (* False *)
> Block[{Internal`$EqualTolerance = -Infinity}, 1 == 1 + $MachineEpsilon/2] (* True *)
> ```

In fact, the value of `` Internal`$EqualTolerance * Log2[10] `` is `7.`, meaning that it ignores the last seven bits, just as I discovered!

(Analogously, `` Internal`$SameQTolerance * Log2[10] `` is `1.`, i.e. it drops the last bit.)

Note that this *is* mentioned in the [documentation for `Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html), under Details:

> - Approximate numbers with machine precision or higher are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits (roughly their last two decimal digits).
> - For numbers below machine precision the required tolerance is reduced in proportion to the precision of the numbers.

However, I never thought to look at it, since (thought) I knew what `==` means!  Lesson learned, always check the documentation, especially if you don't think you need to.

Answer (score 14):

You can define your own "precise equal" using [`Congruent` (`≡`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Congruent.html) (entered as <kbd>Esc</kbd>===<kbd>Esc</kbd> or `\[Congruent]`):

```
Congruent[x_, y_] := Equal @@ SetPrecision[{x, y}, Infinity]
```

Now

```
x ≡ y
```

> ```
> False
> ```

for your example.

Comment: I usually use `Rationalize[_, 0]`, but `SetPrecision[_, Infinity]` actually makes more sense.

Comment: @2012rcampion I would use `SetPrecision`, too. `Rationalize` does something different.  See the answers and discussion in the comments by Mr.Wizard and me [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/funny-behaviour-when-plotting-a-polynomial-of-high-degree-and-large-coefficients/59612#59612).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yikes, thanks for clarifying this.  You weren't kidding about "nearly infinitely many corners."

Comment: @2012rcampion I liked your syntax style use in [your answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76870/18476) more. Hope you don't mind that I adopted it.

Comment: Sure, that's what this site's for!  And nice job spotting the impetus for my question. =)