# What's the usefulness of SymmetricMatrixQ and PositiveDefiniteQ if they fail with this matrix?

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, expression-test

Let's define

```
mat = {{313.95758323354806, 443.4761851932803, 
274.8711923640176}, {443.4761851932803, 
671.32551818649, 417.77978277045105}, 
{274.8711923640176, 417.7797827704511, 
260.0520353920102}};
```

This matrix is Symmetric Positive Definite according to Mathematica.
(Edit to reflect comments) Even `SymmetricMatrixQ[mat, Tolerance -> 0]`, returns `True`.

However, when I do `RandomVariate[InverseWishartMatrixDistribution[10, mat]]` , I simply get `$Failed`. No other error warning, nor any other information... just $Failed. Why is that?
The answer according to comments: Actually, the matrix is not Symmetric, nor is it Positive Definite, even after making it Symmetric.

Hence the question, what's the usefulness of functions like SymmetricMatrixQ and PositiveDefiniteQ which fail for a matrix which is really not at the edge of machine precision?

Comment: Evaluate `mat = 0.5 (mat + Transpose[mat])` before `RandomVariate`. Seems to works then.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for your comment... That seems really strange.  It really works. Why does it work??? SymmetricMatrixQ gives me already true... Is this another machine precision problem?

Comment: `mat` isn't exactly symmetric.  If you change `218.2845921434691` to `218.28459214346907`, it works.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I've just added a matrix which making it symmetric does not work... If I make it symmetric, I lose the PD property.

Comment: @ChrisK You're right, however this 'technique' doesn't seem to work for many matrices! Do you have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Once again, `mat` isn't exactly symmetric.  Changing `417.7797827704511` to `417.7797827704505` does the trick.  Evidently, `PostiveDefiniteMatrixQ` lets some not quite positive definite matrices slide, which causes problems for `InverseWishartMatrixDistribution`.

Comment: Your example `mat` is essentially singular.  Before and after making `mat` really symmetric as suggest by @HenrikSchumacher, one has `MatrixRank[mat]` = 2.  The determinants before and after making `mat` symmetric are -3.18164*10^-11 and -5.57076*10^-10, respectively.  `Eigenvalues[mat]` gives `{1228.88, 16.4601, -1.38849*10^-13}` and `{1228.88, 16.4601, -1.38849*10^-13}` before and after making `mat` symmetric.  `mat` just doesn't cut the mustard as a positive definite matrix.

Comment: @JimB I agree with you... What I don't understand is why would Mathematica have functions like SymmetricMatrixQ and PositiveDefiniteQ which give True to singular matrices which apparently are not really at the edge of machine precision... What's their usefulness?

Comment: I think it's a good thing that functions like `PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ`, `SymmetricMatrixQ` etc. have a `Tolerance` option to allow for a bit of leeway when necessary. Is your contention that you don't like the default value for this tolerance? You can always set it to `Tolerance -> 0` if you prefer, which seems to give them the strict behavior you want.

Comment: @Roman I'm not able to get `SymmetricMatrixQ[mat, Tolerance->0` to give `False` for 11.3 on Windows 10 for `mat`. However, `SymmetricMatrixQ[Rationalize[mat, 0]]` does give `False`. Also, (to An Old Man in the Sea) `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ` does not check for symmetry (not that you said it did).  I think that *Mathematica* (or any software) just can't do all of the quality assurance that might be needed.  `SymmetricMatrixQ` when `True` simply means that the matrix is approximately symmetric rather than exactly symmetric.  If one needs exact symmetry, then one needs to check for exact symmetry.

Comment: @Roman A bit of leeway is nice... What I think this example shows is that it's more than a bit.

Comment: @JimB Agree, but then the help documentation in mathematica should state that by default the functions give True for approximately [property here], not necessarily exact... Even if the matrix is a bit far from machine precision related problems. The documentation, as is, may induce the user in error.

Comment: Considering that even `mat === Transpose[mat]` gives `True` it's not surprising that `SymmetricMatrixQ[mat, Tolerance -> 0]` also gives `True`. I think that there is a more fundamental issue here: `mat[[2,3]]` and `mat[[3,2]]` differ in their last bit of the IEEE-754 binary representation, and are considered equal for all purposes. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76896/different-floating-point-numbers-equal and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983885/is-there-a-normal-equalq-function-in-mathematica

Comment: `Mean[InverseWishartMatrixDistribution[10, mat]]` works and `Variance` works also.  So it is the `RandomVariate` part that is failing.

Comment: Did you send this example to Wolfram? Personally, I find the behaviour not very good ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm not sure anymore...  If I did, then they simply replied something like "it's a feature, not a bug". Maybe you could get a better answer. If so, keep me updated. ;)

Comment: Well, the lack of a clear error message is not a feature ... The matrix is not really positive definite, as Jim says, but a more informative error message wouldn't hurt.